# How frequently is garbage collected? I don't think my objects are being deleted

Tags: java, methods, garbage-collection, android-view, execution

If I have a class delete itself, should its internal methods stop executing? I have a class B that tells class A to remove B from A's ArrayList. I'm fairly certain B only exists in A's ArrayList, and so when I remove it, it should be deleted, right? (NOTE: I've included a Serializable implementation just in case that would have anything to do with how the VM handles my classes, but I did not write in the read- and writeObject methods here. I doubt it will have anything to do with this issue though.)

```
public class A implements Serializable, B_Listener {
    ArrayList<B> bArray;

    public A() {
        bArray = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();
        bArray.add(new B(bArray.size(), this));
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAtIndex(int index) {
        bArray.remove(index);
    }
}

public class B implements Serializable {
    B_Listener listener;
    int index;

    public B(B_Listener listener, int index) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.index = index;
    }

    //This is called at some point in a B's lifetime.
    private void selfDestruct() {
        listener.deleteAtIndex(index);
        Log.w("B.class", "Should this not output? It does.");
    }
}

public interface B_Listener {
    public void deleteAtIndex(int index);
}
```

So the Log.w message executes when I don't believe it should. Therefore, I'm afraid I'm creating java's memory leaks. I've looked and looked throughout my code trying to find where B might be held by a pointer, but I've come up with nothing besides what I intended.

So then I'm asking if garbage is collected at a different time than when B is deleted on my end. If this is the case, then is it safe to say for the time being that I in fact am not holding objects I do not intend to hold?

Extra (NOTE: this might be hard to follow, everything above this should suffice for the problem):
I also have this tagged with Android-Views because I'm developing on Android: my B class holds View objects that point to B as a listener. When I removeView, the View manager or whatever Android has should no longer point to the View, I believe, and when I delete B, all its internal Views should also be deleted, meaning they can no longer hold B in existence by their own listener pointers. I'm just talking this out to see if my understanding here is correct.

Comment: Who is calling `B.selfDestruct()`?

Comment: Are you asking why the second line of "selfDestruct" is still executed after the first one? (Why should it not be?) FWIW Garbage collection should be completely invisible to your app and not interfere with its behaviour at all. All it does is make sure that enough memory is available. Do not try to interact with it.

Comment: B has a several states, and so if B finds itself in a state that suggests it is useless, it calls the selfDestruct(). In my actual code, there is no selfDestruct method, instead the state handler (within B) I've constructed just executes the line listener.deleteAtIndex(index).

I'm not trying to interact with with garbage collection. I'm trying to understand it. I wasn't taught Java, I was taught C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course not.

A method will only "stop executing" if it `return`s, if an exception is thrown, or if the thread is aborted.

The whole point of garbage collection is that it is invisible to you.  Barring special tricks (such as WeakReferences, or checking free memory), it is impossible to tell whether an object has been garbage collected – if you can check whether it exists, that means that you have a reference to it, so it *cannot* be collected.

Comment: In particular, there is no way that `this` gets garbage collected while one of its methods is still running. At the very least, the object that called the current method still has a reference to that object (that might go away after the method call is completed and the stack unwound, but not before).

Comment: Thank you guys! This is what I needed to hear. I had figured garbage collection was instantaneous. Unfortunately, I cannot upvote your response as I am new :(

Comment: I just want to point out that SLaks is responding to the question I start with in the body of this post, for people reading this in the future.

Comment: Btw, there's a difference between when an object is eligible for being GCed, and when it is actually collected. The GC generally doesn't collect objects until it needs to -- that is, until it runs out of space (I'm painting with a bit of a broad brush here). That lets it GC in bulk, which is faster (at the cost of using more RAM).

Answer (score 1):

1. Usually there will be two kinds of GC: minor (every second or so) and major (every hour or so, but if you give your VM enough memory it could as well be a week).
2. Objects are freed in an asynchronous way (it's much more effective to do that in bulk and it helps in keeping the memory unfragmented). They will not be deleted the millisecond they are not accessible.
3. Garbage collection only makes sense when no active *thread* is able to access an object, not when no *object* holds a reference to it. In your code, as long as selfDestruct runs, the thread owns an implicit "this" reference. This causes the object to be, indeed, referenced by a thread - and safe from GC.

Comment: Thanks, this reinforces the answers above and furthers my understanding of GC.